# Why can't I convert i to usize in iterator function?

Tags: rust

I want to print out every value from this vector and I know I can do it with .enumerate, but I'm curious what's wrong with this:

```
fn main() {
  let vec = vec![1,2,3];
  for i in vec.iter() {
    println!("{}", vec[i as usize]);
  }
}
```

I'm new to Rust, so go easy on me.

Here's the error I got from the faulty code:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[{integer}]` cannot be indexed by `&{integer}`
 --> src\main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     println!("{}", vec[i]);
  |                        ^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
  |
  = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[{integer}]>` is not implemented for `&{integer}`
  = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[T]>` is implemented for `usize`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Index<&{integer}>` for `Vec<{integer}>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: You posted an error from a different version of the code, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is the item being iterated and not the iterator itself.
(Like you said) You can use enumerate to get the iterator index variable, and that is the right way if you want to retrieve the usize index of the vector.

```rs
for (i,n) in vec.iter().enumerate()
```

Comment: From the question: “I know I can do it with .enumerate, but I'm curious what's wrong with this”

Comment: @Ry-  indeed but in the question it seemd to be a confusion in what's `i`.The `usize i` returned to index into the vec is given by enumerate, there is no logic in using the numbers into the vec to index into it, so I answered that enumerate is just the way to go for that. No need for twisted solutions for something that is just an x y pb.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to index your vector in this case. `for` yields an element every iteration.

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in v {
    println!("{i}");
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

`Vec::iter` produces an iterator over references to elements (`&something`). In order to cast a reference to `usize` or use a reference as an index, you have to *dereference* it somehow; one way is exactly as the error message that you didn’t post suggests, using the dereferencing operator `*`.

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3];
for i in vec.iter() {
    println!("{}", vec[*i as usize]);
}
```

(It’s also possible to leave out the `as usize` cast, and the type of `vec` will be inferred as `Vec<usize>`.)

Then you run into the issue that `vec[3]` doesn’t exist. If you just wanted to print the contents of the vector, there’s no need to index into `vec`; `.iter()` is already an iterator over the *elements*, not indices, of a vector.

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
for &i in vec.iter() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

(This is also an example of a different way to dereference, by using a reference pattern `&i`, and you can write `for &i in &vec`, too. Or `for i in vec` directly if you don’t need `vec` afterwards, which works on non-copyable types.)